# Given a variable $x$, is its "growth rate" (or "rate of change") $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ or $\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, definition

I think it is (or should be) the latter (reasoning below). But many writers (e.g. [Stewart](https://books.google.com/books?id=1SA9AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA230), *Calculus*) use the former instead.

So I'm confused and hence this question. (Maybe this is just one of those phrases/terms that have different definitions according to the writer?)

---

Say $x_t$ is population, $x_{2021}=100000$, and $x_{2022}=101000$. Then most people would say that the annual growth rate of population was $1\%$: $$g_x=\frac{\frac{x_{2022}-x_{2021}}{1\ \text{year}}}{x_{2021}}=\frac{\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}}{x}.$$

(I don't think many would say that the growth rate of population was $1000$.)

Now going from the above discrete case to the continuous case, shouldn't we similarly have that

$$g_x=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}{x}?$$

Comment: I have seen the term "relative growth rate" for the second concept mentioned in your title, as opposed to just "growth rate" for the first concept.

Comment: Mostly the growth rate is simply $dx/dt$, in your case 1,000 per year.  The second form is the proportionate or logarithmic growth rate, and is equal to $d\log x/dt$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_growth_rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Many calculus textbooks define $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ as the **(absolute) growth rate** and $\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}{x}$ as the **relative growth rate**.
2. But many social scientists (economists, demographers) often simply call the latter the "growth rate".

So, growth rate is $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in math but $\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}{x}$ in the social sciences.

---

1. Stewart, Clegg, and Watson (*Calculus: Early Transcendentals*, 2021), pp. 230, 240:

> growth rate ... $=\frac{dn}{dt}$ ...

> $\frac{dP/dt}{P}$ ... is called the **relative growth rate**.

Briggs, Cochran, Gillett, and Schulz (*Calculus: Early Transcendentals*, 2019), p. 493:

> If $y\left(t\right)$ represents a population, then $y^{\prime}\left(t\right)$ is the **(absolute) growth rate** of the population ... Another way to talk about growth rates is to use the **relative growth rate**, which is the growth rate divided by the current value of the quantity, or $y^{\prime}\left(t\right)/y\left(t\right)$.

Hass, Heil, and Weir (*Thomas' Calculus*, 2018), p. 541:

> $\frac{dP/dt}{P}$ ... is called the **relative growth rate**.

---

2. Abel, Blanchard, Bernanke, and Croushore (*Macroeconomics*, [2017](https://books.google.com/books?id=vegsEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT968)):

> Let $\Delta X/X$ and $\Delta Z/Z$ represent the growth rates

[Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/future-population-growth):

> The global population growth rate has already slowed down considerably: it reached its peak at over 2% in the 1960s and has been falling since.

Mankiw (*Principles of Economics*, [2020](https://books.google.com/books?id=KQfFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA369)):

> With a growth rate of 2 percent per year, productivity and real wages double about every 35 years.

Answer (score 1):

> Say $x_t$ is population, $x_{2021}=100000$, and $x_{2022}=101000$. Then most people would say that the **annual growth rate** of population was $1\%$: $$g_x=\frac{\frac{x_{2022}-x_{2021}}{1\ \text{year}}}{x_{2021}}=\frac{\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}}{x}.$$

Your formula gives the **relative average annual growth**; more clearly: the *average* annual growth [relative to the base case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4494031/21813). Here, the time dimension is related to the averaging process rather than to the 'percentaging' process.

On the other hand, the **average annual growth rate** is actually $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ or $$\frac1{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\,\mathrm dt,$$ where the measurements are taken yearly and $t$ corresponds to years.

Answer (score 0):

The growth rate is the rate at which a population is increasing (or decreasing) during a year. In this case, i think the rate is a positive rate of 1000 per year.
However, this growth rate is usually expressed as a percentage of the base population. (1000 / 100000)*100 = 1% .